# Angular2 attribute directive does not work in components rendered in RouterOutlet?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have been using NG2 since the final release 2.0.2 now 2.4.1. Attribute Directives work in simple case like what in the tutorial at https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html, and all tutorials I could find are also with simple case of rendering the directive declared immediately in app.component.html. However, I have components rendered in router outlet as defined in app.component.html like this:

```
    <nav>
    <a routerLink="/" routerLinkActive="active">  </a>
</nav>
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I declare the directive in app.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
...
    declarations: [

        //** Root level components
        AppComponent,

        HomeComponent,
...
        HighlightDirective,

    ],
```

And the feature modules with routes are declared in app-routing.module.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },

    { path: 'ml_payment', loadChildren: 'app/payment/payment.module#PaymentModule', canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: 'account', loadChildren: 'app/account/account.module#AccountModule', canActivate: [AuthGuard, AdminGuard] },
    { path: 'wip', component: WIPComponent },

    { path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent },

];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

When the nested components are rendered, NG2 runtime do not render myHighlight into respective style tag of HTML. I just wonder if I had missed something or NG2 custom attribute directives do not work with RouterOutlet?

Comment: any error you can see ?

Comment: No error in F12 of browser. However, I am sure the constructor of the directive class is not called.

Comment: Where should it render `myHighlight`. I don't see it added anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 1):

use routerLinkActive as [routerLinkActive]="['active']"

```
   <nav>
    <a routerLink="/" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">  </a>
</nav>
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the syntax you use is probably for older pre-release of ng2. In final releases, such syntax is for other purpose.

Answer (score 0):

@ZZZ, did you put the directive in the "exports" section of the module where it was declared? Today I had a similar issue when I forgot to export a directive.

Good luck.